# Gradle sync failed: Could not find any matches for spde.build:sep-local-pack

Tags: android, gradle

### When I open project exists in computer, I'm having a problem with gradle build:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find any matches for spde.build:sep-local-pack:25.2.+ as no versions of spde.build:sep-local-pack are available.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/D:/AndroidWorkspace/AS/gradle/m2repository/spde/build/sep-local-pack/maven-metadata.xml
file:/D:/AndroidWorkspace/AS/gradle/m2repository/spde/build/sep-local-pack/
Required by:
project :Camera
```

---

### Here is the code in build.gradle:

```
project.ext.set('apiCode', ((project.hasProperty('API')) ? API : 'L25.2'))
...//More code
if(apiCode.startsWith('G')){
    classpath "spde.build:sep-global-pack:" + apiCode+ ".+"
}else if (apiCode.startsWith('L')){
    classpath "spde.build:sep-local-pack:" + apiCode+ ".+"
}
...//more code.
```

---

I tried reinstall AS and using SDK from another computer which is build normal. But this error still happens to my computer.
Please help me! Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @Trung Doan , were you able to resolve this error? If yes how?

Comment: In my company. this project is need to download library in repository. but i doesn't config them.
So after i added init.gradle file which has config to download library to .gradle folder then it built successfully

Comment: I think we work in the same company :). Can you please let me know the exact steps followed as the problem I'm facing is the exact same one as you have described.I can't find any init.gradle file in the project.

Comment: i work at samsung electronics company. if we work in the same company. please contact me via mysingle: doan.pt.